# Criar backup automatico no sqlserver e enviar e-mail de confirmação

Tags: backup

Preciso criar um BACKUP automático diário para um banco de dados em sqlserver.
- O nome do backup deve seguir o seguinte padrão: BACKUP_BANCO_DIA_MES_ANO;

- Após criar o BACKUP, enviar um e-mail do status (SUCESSO ou ERRO);
- Se SUCESSO, copiar o BACKUP para o Google Drive e apagar o BACKUP anterior;
- Se ERRO, enviar e-mail informando o erro.

Encontrei esse tutorial, mas não entendi muito bem como usá-lo: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/07feb406-2bf4-478a-8aab-9abbbac97968/script-backup-sql-express?forum=admingeralpt

Desde já agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Ola, eu vi esse tutorial e usei esse utilitario muito bom por sinal ele e muito simples!
segue exemplo!

Apos você ter instalado você só precisara conectar o utilitários a sua instancia do sql como a imagem abaixo!

[image: IMAGEM1]

logo apos ter feito o login com sucesso você so precisa configurar o processo
de Backup/e-mail como exemplo a imagem abaixo!

[image: exemplo2]

Pronto esta configurado e bem simples!

Comment: wallafe souza, pesquisei sobre essa ferramenta, parece muito boa mesmo! Você chegou a usar a versão paga?

Comment: Não Amigo, não uso paga, pois a free já supri minhas necessidades!